# Python : How do you remove 'In []' and 'Out []' for a .html export of .ipynb / Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, html, jupyter-notebook

I often export my .ipynb file to .html format. It would be great to know how to remove the 'In []' and 'Out []' part of .ipynb files in Jupyter Notebook or in HTML after being exported to a .html file.

[I would like to remove those parts pointed by the arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTkHC.png)

Comment: it should be method to use own template (created with `Jinja2`) with `jupyter-nbconvert`. I found only [Custom Templates for Jupyter Notebooks with Jinja2](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/jinja2-custom-export-templates-jupyter)

Answer (score 3):

I think this might help you:

```
jupyter nbconvert --to html --TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True --TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True <your_file>.ipynb
```

Setting **TemplateExporter.exclude_input_prompt=True** removes the in []
Similarly **TemplateExporter.exclude_output_prompt=True** removes the out [] from the generated .html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow [tour]. Please [edit] your answer and add an explanation about the code you posted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be simply achieved using `--no-prompt` flag:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert --to html --no-prompt  your_notebook.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Run Jupyter notebook and download the notebook in the browser: 
   File->Download as->HTML and you will get a html page with code and output.
2. Open the exported HTML with browser and activate the browser console with key F12
3. Run following command in the console:

   document.querySelectorAll("div.input").forEach(function(a){a.remove()})

The code removes all input div DOM. Then right mouse button and chose "Save Page As" and Save the "Complete page" (not single page).

You will get a page with an associated folder in windows. Use a trick by zip the html page and then extract to unbind the associated. The folder is useless.

Now it is a single html page without code. You can re-distribute it or print it as PDF.

Comment: Hi, this doesn't remove the  'In []' and 'Out []' . Instead, it removes the code. I would like to keep the code but not  'In []' and 'Out []'. Thanks

Comment: then I think you should use editor and use find and replace tool.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the **.jp-OutputPrompt** and **.jp-InputPrompt** in the css section of the HTML document

```
color: transparent !important;
```